# Can't display both projector and built in display simultaneously

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, projector, compaq

I have a Compaq Presario CQ60 laptop connected to an Acer K330 projector using VGA.  I can use the built in display or the projector, but it won't let me use both at once.  If I pick mirror or join it goes back and forth between the two, but never both.  How can I fix it?  Ubuntu 18.04.1.

Answer (score 0):

Check the details for the Graphics Chipset. I have a Dell Latitude with the same problem due to a hardware restriction.

Comment: seems to be intel gm45, what do i do with that info?  :)

Comment: Check the hardware restrictions on the Intel website. It may only allow a single display at a time.

Comment: do you mean the site @abaddon s found?  that's the only official one i can find.

Answer (score 0):

check this page [Intel-82GM45](https://ark.intel.com/products/35134/Intel-82GM45-Graphics-and-Memory-Controller-Hub)
Particularly where said:

> Displays Supported ‡ 2

but at the foot of the page says :

> This feature may not be available on all computing systems. Please check with the system vendor to determine if your system delivers this feature, or reference the system specifications (motherboard, processor, chipset, power supply, HDD, graphics controller, memory, BIOS, drivers, virtual machine monitor-VMM, platform software, and/or ***operating system***) for feature compatibility. Functionality, performance, and other benefits of this feature may vary depending on system configuration.

Comment: does ubuntu document anywhere that it shouldn't work?  i happened to notice today that if i log out, the ubuntu login screen *does* work on both screens simultaneously.  it's only once logging in that one turns off.